# Should I use CSS variables for existing HTML colour names

Tags: css, sass

For example, I have the CSS code where I use the white colour a lot.

```
:root {
   --color-white: #fff;
}
```

My question is whether it worths to declare colours like 'black' and 'white' as variables or I shall use default `white` and `black` CSS colour names? Which way is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if efficiency is the driving force behind the use of CSS variables in the way suggested.

There is no need, and indeed it could cause confusion, to rename existing CSS colors.

CSS variables though make it easier to change things. For example, if you are trying out a theme with text in black on white and if there are several places in your CSS where you need to set color or background-color you could define --col: black and --bg: white and then use var(--col) etc in the relevant places in the style sheet.

If you then want to change them, all you have to do is redefine --col and --bg.